# $U_p$ operator is not compact on $p$-adic modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I know that one of the reasons for introducting overconvergent $p$-adic modular forms is that the $U_p$ operator is compact on them.

Is there an easy way to see that $U_p$ is not compact on non-overconvergent $p$-adic modular forms ?

Comment: Morally, I think the answer is "because there's no reason why it should be". The reason you get compactness on the overconvergent spaces is that $U_p$ makes overconvergent things more overconvergent, and that statement just evaporates when you drop the overconvergence condition.

Comment: $U:=U_p$ is compact on $p$-adic modular forms of, say, weight 1 and level 1, because this space is zero-dimensional for trivial reasons. A relatively simple proof that if there's a $U$-eigenform in your space then $U$ is not compact is in Gouvea's thesis -- using operators like $U$ and $V$ and infinite converging sums, you can go from your eigenform to an eigenform with $U$-eigenvalue 0 to an eigenform with $U$-eigenvalue anything in the maximal ideal of your base field, so in particular there are uncountably many eigenforms all with different non-zero eigenvalues so $U$ can't be compact.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I have now both a philosphical and a technical reason. Couldn't ask for more :)